# Is my Trainer over the norm harsh?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

I am an apprentice for informatics. My Trainer does not like me and that is fine.  He scolds me on a regular basis, I am not a flagship student and he has the right and reason to scold me. It just feels like a bit too much than constructive scolding

I just want a comparison with your worst experience with a colleague/supervisor,
So I know **if that is normal or way too harsh, or even nothing in comparison to your experience.**

An Extract of a conversation we had lately
(translated)

> **Trainer**
> ...
> so much for I'm done and tested
> { link to ticket with error_log entry }
> should I run to {the ceo} and cry now too?
> that {my trainer} wastes time pointlessly
> when he looks at the half-finished stuff
> { later }
> **Me**:
> I can't recreate the error ...
> **Trainer**:
> then search
> I don't have time to repeatedly debug your errors
> **Me**:
> yesyes
> can you just copy the config.php into the chat
> **Trainer**:
> best be quiet now!
> otherwise you will experience yes yes
> why should I copy something for you somewhere
> I take your dist settings and entered my mail server password
> I can't go wrong with that
> So you should make sure that you submit correct things
> and don't waste my time
> !!!
> **ME**:
> it works fine on my computer
> **Trainer**:
> always the same with you
> { later: }
> { I found, that the error was, that he copied a wrong version of the config without the constants }
> **Me**:
> ...
> I could reproduce the error
> You copied the wrong config
> **Trainer**:
> I can only copy what is there at the time of the review
> so just learn that I can only review the shit you give in the repo!
> **Me**:
> no idea how that could happen.
> **Trainer**:
> look in the mirror.
> always the same
> **Me**:
> In any case, the log says that you are missing important php constants like {Constant}
> **Trainer**:
> the procedure costs me unnecessarily time
> you should test your code yourself, i'm not your minion who does the dirty work every time
> maybe you will learn that at some point
> that I only test the state that you give me
> **Me**:
> so what now?
> **Trainer**:
> -.-

Comment: What exactly is this "Trainer"?

Comment: People blaming you for their mistakes is, unfortunately, somewhat common. That being said, the trainer is a jerk. Yes, the language is unusually harsh.

Comment: Your trainer is an asshole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Based on the transcript you provided you trainer seems to be not really interested in teaching you. Whether it's overly harsh would depend on the location you are from etc., but at least where I'm from (Germany) this would certainly be perceived as too much.

As said in the summary, what is overly harsh will likely depend a lot on the country you are from. Anyway, I do not think harsh is the best word to describe your advisor. It is more likely your advisor is either under immense stress himself or just plainly not interested in teaching you anything. This is the conclusion I made from reading the following snippets:

> ME:
> it works fine on my computer
> Trainer:
> always the same with you

No useful advise offered

> Me:
> no idea how that could happen.
> Trainer:
> look in the mirror.
> always the same

Neither here

> Me:
> so what now?
> Trainer:
> -.-

and certainly not here.
Although the most interesting part to me was this except:

> Trainer:
> I can only copy what is there at the time of the review
> so just learn that I can only review the shit you give in the repo!

where he qualitatively judges your work.

Some information on my perspective, I'm a PhD student both teaching programming and data analysis to other students/colleagues and learning about data processing from them. While learning stuff myself, I had all types of different teachers, some similar to your trainer, but still a little more professional.
Although people are supposed to already have substantial background knowledge when doing their PhD or similar, everybody brings in slightly different background knowledge. This results in different knowledge gaps. So everybody got to learn something along the way. Therefore, as you are an apprentice, not a senior employee, you are expected to have gaps in your knowledge and that is fine. You are an apprentice for the purpose of expanding your knowledge. Otherwise you'd be hired in e.g. a senior position.

In case you want some advice on how to deal with that (you did not specifically ask) I'd suggest you either try to 'suck it up', learn as much as possible and look for a better position when possible, you are not gonna be an apprentice forever. If you have the feeling that the pressure is to much for you (which is neither a shame nor a sign of weakness), I'd suggest you look for another apprenticeship.

Comment: Another solution would be to look for another, more pedagogically-inclined trainer. If this trainer is not OP’s manager, then OP could report to their manager. If this trainer *is* OP’s manager as well, OP could escalate to their trainer’s manager.

Comment: @breversa  we are a company with about 30 people ~ 15 devs ~10 php devs he is he only one licensed for training apprentices. Manager has other things to do. Ill do i, like VoodooCode suggested: I'll suck it up as i did 2 years already.

Comment: @temporarymaintainerofthis Are you saying you've been at this job for two years and you still have a "trainer" assigned to you? That's a worrying sign. Not because it means you're doing badly, necessarily, but because it means the company don't trust you to do well by yourself. And if your company don't trust you after two years of working for them, that's *bad*. Take it from me.